# Why are some questions highlighted in blue?

Tags: discussion

I know this is a seriously newbie question, but I can't find it in the FAQ and I have encountered and not understood it on this and other SE sites.

Why are some questions highlighted in blue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is highlighting questions with tags that are in your favorite tags.  If you haven't manually added any favorite tags, the system will detect when you have a certain level of activity in a tag and infer one for you.  If you manually add a favorite tag, the system will not infer a tag for you.

You can customize your favorite (and ignored tags) in [your profile](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/435/waf?tab=prefs).  You can also customize these settings in the right sidebar of the homepage and the /questions listing.

So, if you would prefer not to have any questions highlighted, you can simply add a nonsense "tag" to your favorites.  Perhaps [unicorn](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicorn)? (:

Comment: Unicorn? [Not](http://www.zootorah.com/essays/unicorn.html) as off-topic as you might hope. :) I was sorely tempted to post a question about the tachash and tag it unicorn, just show it'd show up under your link.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, oy.  Feel free to edit in a more appropriate nonsense tag. (:

Comment: I could try, but someone would find a valid Jewish reference to it too, somewhere.